# Deserializing JSON Array to Object in C#

Tags: c#, html, json, api, serialization

I'm reletively new to C# (previous experience with HTML/JS/Angular) and I am having issues with deserializing the JSON i'm reciving back from an API I am using.

```
{  
   "titles":[  
  {  
     "lastUnlock":"2016-12-28T16:34:36.0390000Z",
     "titleId":566278,
     "serviceConfigId":"6ee10100-671e-4fc4-8cf1-91700008a406",
     "titleType":"DGame",
     "platform":"Durango",
     "name":"Game1",
     "earnedAchievements":4,
     "currentGamerscore":60,
     "maxGamerscore":1000
  },
  {  
     "lastUnlock":"2016-08-05T13:02:18.4140000Z",
     "titleId":10027721,
     "serviceConfigId":"28dd0100-1521-414e-a1d8-f0ba009902c9",
     "titleType":"DGame",
     "platform":"Durango",
     "name":"Game2",
     "earnedAchievements":17,
     "currentGamerscore":1000,
     "maxGamerscore":1000
  },
  {  
     "lastUnlock":"2016-05-02T20:52:40.3705214Z",
     "titleId":62572131,
     "serviceConfigId":"54240100-7870-4a47-8cec-7cfd03bac663",
     "titleType":"DGame",
     "platform":"Durango",
     "name":"Game3",
     "earnedAchievements":35,
     "currentGamerscore":1000,
     "maxGamerscore":1000
  },
     ],
   "pagingInfo":{  
      "continuationToken":null,
      "totalRecords":86
   }
}
```

The issue is I am not sure how to deserialize this in to an array of objects.

I have created an object class:

```
public class Game
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string gamertag { get; set; }
        public string platform { get; set; }
        public int earnedAchievements { get; set; }
        public string currentGamerscore { get; set; }
        public string maxGamerscore { get; set; }
        public string lastUnlock { get; set; }
    }
```

From there i've tried using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result) but this just returns "CompleteAdmin.Controllers.AchievementsAPIController+Game" which isn't usable.

Can anybody show me how this is supposed to be setup? Ultimately i'm aiming to get this in to a DB. :)

Thanks.

Comment: TThis is how to do it with Json.NET https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: As far as I can see that's pretty much my current setup: 

games = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(result);

Comment: If your JSON is a collection then it would be JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Game>> or whatever collection it is.

Comment: Just a heads up, when trying to deserialize your JSON I got an error message about a trailing comma that shouldn't be there. It's the second one counting back from `pagingInfo`.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple like

in visual studio right click on the solution and choose "Manage NuGet Packages" a menu will be open in the top search type "newtonsoft" select the very first option with black icon. and add to your project. then write the following.

```
public class Games
{
    public Game[] titles { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{


    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gamertag { get; set; }
    public string platform { get; set; }
    public int earnedAchievements { get; set; }
    public string currentGamerscore { get; set; }
    public string maxGamerscore { get; set; }
    public string lastUnlock { get; set; }
}
```

On page load or where you want the result :

```
 string jsonObject = @"{  
                                   'titles':[  
                                  {  
                                     'lastUnlock':'2016-12-28T16:34:36.0390000Z',
                                     'titleId':566278,
                                     'serviceConfigId':'6ee10100-671e-4fc4-8cf1-91700008a406',
                                     'titleType':'DGame',
                                     'platform':'Durango',
                                     'name':'Game1',
                                     'earnedAchievements':4,
                                     'currentGamerscore':60,
                                     'maxGamerscore':1000
                                  },
                                  {  
                                     'lastUnlock':'2016-08-05T13:02:18.4140000Z',
                                     'titleId':10027721,
                                     'serviceConfigId':'28dd0100-1521-414e-a1d8-f0ba009902c9',
                                     'titleType':'DGame',
                                     'platform':'Durango',
                                     'name':'Game2',
                                     'earnedAchievements':17,
                                     'currentGamerscore':1000,
                                     'maxGamerscore':1000
                                  },
                                  {  
                                     'lastUnlock':'2016-05-02T20:52:40.3705214Z',
                                     'titleId':62572131,
                                     'serviceConfigId':'54240100-7870-4a47-8cec-7cfd03bac663',
                                     'titleType':'DGame',
                                     'platform':'Durango',
                                     'name':'Game3',
                                     'earnedAchievements':35,
                                     'currentGamerscore':1000,
                                     'maxGamerscore':1000
                                  },
                                     ],
                                   'pagingInfo':{  
                                      'continuationToken':null,
                                      'totalRecords':86
                                   }
                                }";


        var games = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Games>(jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra class to contain your collection of `Titles` (or `Games`, better make up your mind...)

```
public class Container
{
    public Game[] Titles { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can easily deserialize like this:

```
var res = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Container>(jsonObject);
```

To use this, add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` to your project.

Note that I had to remove a comma from your JSON to get this to work:

```
 },    <------ this comma should not be there
  ],
"pagingInfo":{  
   "continuationToken":null,
   "totalRecords":86
}
```